# Load localized string from my app inside a static lib?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, localization, translation

I have a project divided in layers, and the bottom one is included in the top one as a static lib.

The thing is that I need to localize a string in the static lib, using the translations present in my app (upper layer).

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I managed to do this is loading the strings from a bundle instead of using `NSLocalizedString`:

```
+ (NSString *)getTranslationFromAppBundleForString:(NSString *)originalText {

    NSString * lang = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString * bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:lang ofType:@"lproj"];
    NSBundle * bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];

    return [bundle localizedStringForKey:originalText value:originalText table:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an LanguageAgent in your static library, add a bundle ressource in that library. Then use a function like this to get localizedString. In my application, I separate language by different table (see picture below for a table named 'Dictionaire'. You can have more than 1 table in your languages bundle.

```
-(NSString*) myLocalizedStringForKey:(NSString*) key ofTable:(NSString*)tableName {
    //I save selected language in my NSUserDefaults.
    NSString *selectedLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DefaultLanguage"];

    if (selectedLanguage == nil) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"en" forKey:@"DefaultLanguage"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
        selectedLanguage = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"DefaultLanguage"];
     }

    NSString *langBundleNew = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/langs/Languages.bundle/%@.lproj/",selectedLanguage]; //use your path to the Languages.bundle here. 

    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:langBundleNew]) {
        NSBundle *aBundle = (NSBundle*)[self.dictLangueBundle objectForKey:selectedLanguage];
         NSString* str=[aBundle localizedStringForKey:key value:@"[string not defined]" table:tableName];
         return str;
    } else {
        return @"[]";
    }
}
```

My language bundle is similar like this: ('Dictionaire' = name of the table)

[image]

Here is a sample of content in my Dictionnaire.strings for 'en.lproj':

[image]

Comment: One thing I don't understand here is where does the languages.bundle exist? Is it in the scope of your static lib, or within the app that actually uses the lib? Thanks!

Comment: You can integrate languages.bundle to your static library or add this files to your main project. In my code, I add to my main project, then when application start, I move it to a folder in Library. Cause I want this file to be modifiable.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/ios-library-with-resources/

Comment: Yeah, I understand. But you would have to copy to a folder from the main app and know what is this app in your lib beforehand. With the snippet I posted, you don't care where each file is, and you only get it from the bundle. Thanks anyway for the idea!